# Is fuel tank pressure structurally important?

Tags: fuel, engineering

Being super lightweight structures, do rockets depend to some degree on internal pressure of their fuel tanks for structural integrity?

Comment: Even if a tank is designed for equal pressure inside and outside, it would be destroyed by relatively small positive or negative pressure differences. A small differential pressure acting on the very large surface of the tank would create huge forces.